# Problemas con referencias en visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, referencias

soy nuevo en esto, [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un problema que ya nose como resolverlo, el año pasado tenia instalado un programa llamado devexpress en visual estudio(en disco D), para practicar ya que en mi trabajo lo usan, hace unos meses cuando cambie a un disco mas grande, lo reinstale en disco C, pero no me reconoce la nueva ubicación de los dll que visual estudio necesita para compilar, dejo las capturas, si alguno le paso algo similar o save como resolverlo, yo reistale el visual studio pero no me funciono.

Comment: Anda a la carpeta del proyecto y busca el archivo con extensión `.csproj` lo abres con el bloc de notas, buscas las dll's con problema y asignas la nueva ruta